# No module named 'codecs' ---Mac

Tags: python, module

I've been desperately trying to solve my problem by my own, looking some information on the Internet. However, none of them can solve my problem. I've been programming for 2-3 years, this is my first time seeing this error. I can't do any programming without solving it.
The following is my error when I type "pip3 install codecs" (or type pip install also ran the same error).

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8'
  sys.base_prefix = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8'
  sys.executable = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8'
  sys.prefix = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8'
  sys.path = [
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'
```

I need help, thanks!!!

Comment: `codecs` is standard module and it should be installed with Python and you can't install it with `pip`. You may have to reinstall Python to get also `codecs`

Comment: @furas I reinstalled python, but still not working.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and you reinstalled one Python but you still run with other Python.  You could check if you can run `python3.6`, `python3.7`, `python3.8`, `python3.9` (or `pip3.6`, `pip3.7`, `pip3.8`, `pip3.9`)